# Python converting a list of different lists with different timestamps into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a biglist to which different dataframes where appended through a for loop operation. Now the biglist has different lists. Some of this sublists have matching timestamp and some dont. I want to convert this biglist into a dataframe with each data included.
My code:

```
biglist = 

[
                                                     column1
 11/09/2020 5:25:44 AM                                  36
 11/09/2020 5:34:55 AM                                  35
 11/09/2020 5:34:56 AM                                  36
 11/09/2020 5:39:36 AM                                  35
 11/09/2020 5:39:37 AM                                  36
 11/09/2020 6:29:02 PM                                  45
 11/09/2020 6:55:47 PM                                  45
 11/09/2020 6:59:41 PM                                  43
 11/09/2020 7:25:47 PM                                  43
 11/09/2020 7:30:58 PM                                  42
 [10 rows x 1 columns],
                                                 column2
 11/09/2020 9:37:47 AM                           11677
 11/09/2020 5:27:55 PM                           11677,
                                              column3
 11/09/2020 9:37:47 AM                     1.33108e+06
 11/09/2020 5:27:55 PM                     1.33108e+06,
                                                    Column4
 11/09/2020 6:23:25 AM                              0.972756
 11/09/2020 6:39:04 AM                               1.90602
 11/09/2020 6:45:10 AM                               2.41583
 11/09/2020 6:45:49 AM                               2.93376
 11/09/2020 6:49:13 AM                               3.83149
 11/09/2020 5:22:39 PM                               2.12865
 11/09/2020 5:25:28 PM                               3.15538
 11/09/2020 5:29:15 PM                               2.12897
 11/09/2020 5:47:06 PM                                1.1835
 11/09/2020 6:27:07 PM                              0.971422
 
 [10 rows x 1 columns]]
df = pd.concat(biglist)
```

Present output:

The dataframe basically copied all the index in the list. It did not actually produce a single index. Instead, first list index and column1 would appear first, then second list index and column2 would follow next. Instead, I was expecting a single index which consists all the index and all the columns. Some columns could have NaN when they have no data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge` instead:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1], [1], [4]], columns=['A'], index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2], [3], [6]], columns=['B'], index=['i1', 'i2', 'i4'])
biglist = [df1, df2]
final_df = biglist[0]
for df in biglist[1:]:
    final_df = final_df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
print(final_df)

      A    B
i1  1.0  2.0
i2  1.0  3.0
i3  4.0  NaN
i4  NaN  6.0
```